# Have Mercury/Gemini/Apollo produced any unmanned descendants?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, russia, uncrewed-spaceflight, united-states

It is well known that Russian manned spacecrafts gave birth to multiple unmanned satellite projects (such as [Bion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bion_%28satellite%29) spacecrafts, for example).

Have Mercury/Gemini/Apollo spacecrafts or their direct descendant projects ever been used as unmanned satellite projects (not counting the test flights for the manned programs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, yes, all mentioned systems have been *tested* in space in *unmanned* flights as you have noted. Some of those flights carried animals (e.g. [Mercury-Atlas 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Atlas_5) and [Mercury-Redstone 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Redstone_2)) and a few experiments on e.g. life support.

On the contrary, nothing has actually been build which could match [Bion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bion-M_No.1) or [Zond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zond_program#Circumlunar_missions) spacecrafts. As of today, those Soviet / Russian programs are still fairly unique.

There were a number of proposals for "spin-offs" of the mentioned programs. [Gemini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gemini#Proposed_extensions_and_applications) saw a few ideas towards an advanced transportation craft and, most notable, an intensive program on potential military use. For Apollo, there was the [Apollo Applications Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Applications_Program). There were tons of concepts, e.g. even one for a manned Venus-Flyby with Apollo technology. In the end, Skylab became the only actual "spin-off" of the Apollo program. Politically, the focus was directed on manned space flight, thus astronauts supervising experiments in space.